# How to monitor React events while debugging

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid, dom-events, ag-grid-react

How can I check what React events are fired in particular situations?

I am developing a react component which uses Ag grid react internally. Ag Grid React has events like `rowDataChanged`, `rowDataUpdated`. While debugging, I am interested to know which Ag Grid events are fired.

Is it possible in Chrome? Or is there any other tool to check this?

Answer (score 3):

1. Hit F12 to open Dev Tools
2. Click the Sources tab
3. On right-hand side, scroll down to "Event Listener Breakpoints", and expand tree
4. Click on the events you want to listen for.
5. Interact with the target element, if they fire you will get a break point in the 
   debugger

Answer (score 0):

Try console logging the event.

```
rowDataChanged={(e) => console.log(e, "rowDataChanged")}
```

React has some developer tools that you may find useful.

https://github.com/facebook/react-devtools

Comment: Hi Will, Thank you for reply.

I named those 2 events just as examples. Actually I don't know which events are getting fired while debugging. I need to check any react event that is fired from ag-grid-react.

Comment: with react-dev tools, I am not able to monitor the react events. only  I can see the react component hierarchy, including component props and state.